# clickButton in extendsFragment

Tags: android, android-studio

Помогите пожалуйста, что это за ошибка ?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ..., PID: 15686
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method calculate (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10815)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

CalculateActivity.Java

```
package ...;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalculatorActivity extends Fragment {


    TextView calculateTextView;

    EditText sumEditText;
    EditText monthEditText;

   // Integer sum;
   // Integer months;
   // Integer percent;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator_main, container, false);
    //    sumEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.sumEditText);
    //    monthEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.monthEditText);
   //      calculateTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.calculateTextView);
        return view; //inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator_main, container, false);
    }
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("CrCal");
    }
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

}
```

Comment: android:onClick работает только в активити, не в фрагментах. Называть фрагмент что то там Activity идеологически неверно.

Comment: А как ещё можно реализовать кнопку Button т.к. я создал шаблон Navigate Drawer Activity? мне надо чтобы в при переключении сработал button, а тут один вариант с фрагментами... хм.?

Comment: Второй или третий [способ](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php#click)